# Simple navigation bar roll over gap

Tags: html, css, nav

just a quick simple html/css question im sure someone will be able to answer easily. Im a coding novice, hence why im asking :)

So im making a navigation bar, made from an unordered list wrapped in a div tag with a roll over to change the background colour of each link. (I hope my coding lingo makes sense)
Heres my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Thomson Automotive Ebay Store</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #navbar ul {
            background-color: #000;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        #navbar ul li {
            display: inline;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        #navbar ul li a {
            color: #FFF;
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 10px 10px;
        }
        #navbar ul li a:hover {
            background-color: #0085D7;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ADD TO FAVORITES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">DELIVERY & RETURNS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FEEDBACK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

So my only problem is when preview it in Firefox, when I roll over my link, the background color change doesnt seem fill up my nav bar properly, leaving a 1-2 pixle gap at the bottom as seen here:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/psUK9.jpg

Minor, I know, but just wanted to know if there was a problem with my coding, or if its just a browser issue.

Thanks :)

Comment: Looks good in my Firefox (v26):  http://jsfiddle.net/N7khC/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding from `#navbar ul`.

Add these properties `#navbar ul li a`:

`{line-height: 40px;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0px 10px;}`

Line-height will determine the height of your nav, and vertically center your text as well! Inline-Block gives the  height so you don't need any padding top or bottom, just sides.